# TestCafe: Issues with concurrent tests across diffferent browsers

Tags: testing, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I have a Fixture with 4 tests, I want to test this Fixture 2 different browsers. So I run below command:

```
testcafe -c 1 chrome,firefox testsfolder/
```

I am using `t.fixtureCtx` to set values across these 4 tests because I need to refer values from one test to another. I was expecting that it will spin up one instance each of Chrome and FF and run entire test independent of each other (browser).

However, the issue I am facing is that the tests do not stay in their lane. In other words, values set by Chrome in **Test#1** are used by Firefox in its **Test#2**.

I can always run these tests separately in two separate commands however I wanted to test it on multiple browsers in a single command. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [t.fixtureCtx object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/fixturectx.html) is created once before fixture tests run on the server side, and it is shared between several browsers. This behavior is by design.

I suggest you save shared values as an object according to the browser name.

For example:

```
const logTimestamp = t => {
    if (!t.fixtureCtx.sharedData)
        t.fixtureCtx.sharedData = {};

    const browser = t.browser.name;

    if (!t.fixtureCtx.sharedData[browser]) {
        t.fixtureCtx.sharedData[browser] = { timestamp: new Date().getTime() };
    }
};

fixture`Fixture 1`
    .page`about:blank`;

test('Test 1', async t => {    
    await t.wait(1000);
    logTimestamp(t);
    
    console.log(`Test 1, browser: ${t.browser.name},  timestamp: ${t.fixtureCtx.sharedData[t.browser.name].timestamp}`);
});

test('Test 2', async t => {    
    await t.wait(1000);
    
    console.log(`Test 2, browser: ${t.browser.name},  timestamp: ${t.fixtureCtx.sharedData[t.browser.name].timestamp}`);
});
```